# Using Google Analytics for an API

Tags: google-analytics

I have a small API written in node.js that has no website attached, it works only on AJAX calls. I want to know if it is possible to use Google Analytics, or other good Analytics tool to monitor traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on how you have things set up but I wonder if you couldn't just add the normal JavaScript tracking to your API since its JavaScript as well.  In the event you cant do that you should check out the [Measurement Protocol Overview](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/), it will allow you to send the raw data to Google Analytics yourself.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at this.

Comment: I found this https://www.npmjs.org/package/universal-analytics. Looks pretty handy, its based on your suggestion.

Comment: Only downside of this method is that the IP from the server will be taken, and not the end-user.